# Programatically Access the Citrix Receiver and Connection Center

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, citrix, receiver, xenapp

I would like to add some functionality to an app which is run from thin clients which are connected to a Citrix Farm.

All this needs to do is open the Citrix Connection Centre (This is done by right clicking Citrix Receiver and then clicking Connection Centre), open the 'preferences' option, and then close the Connection Centre again. This resolves an issue we are having and I would like to automate this for our users.

Can anyone please suggest a way of achieving this through the use of the .NET framework? Any advice is much appreciated.

I am working within the .NET-3.5 framework with Citrix 7.6

Comment: Did you check out the developer forum https://developer.citrixonline.com/

Comment: Hi C0dingJammer, I have but it only seems possible to do this sort of thing server-side where I need the app to run from a client's desktop. Also, the APIs all seem to be geared towards Citrix GoToMeeting or GoToTraining, I just have a range of citrix servers with users connecting with a session. I want to give the users some level of control of their own session via the app, so that support don't have to deal with every single query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this with the following :

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\ICA Client\concentr.exe");
IntPtr windowPtr = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, "Citrix Connection Center");
SetForegroundWindow(windowPtr);
SendKeys.SendWait("{r}");
IntPtr prefWindowPtr = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, "Citrix Receiver - Preferences");
SendMessage(prefWindowPtr, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
SendMessage(windowPtr, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Which does :

- Open Citrix Connection Center (concentr.exe)
- Bring window to the front
- Send the R key (this opens preferences)
- Close both windows (concentr and preferences)

See [pinvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/) for details on the invoked methods `FindWindowByCaption`, `SetForegroundWindow` and `SendMessage`